# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Cascading Dropdown on Edit View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to learn ASP.NET MVC 4 (go easy on me...) and am having trouble making a cascading dropdown work correctly on an Edit view.

I followed [this article](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1482/cascading-dropdownlist-using-ajax-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-4) and have a cascading dropdown correctly populating options from my MSSQL db on my Create view and saving to the db, but I cannot get the dropdown to correctly populate with the already saved value from the MSSQL db when editing a record.

I feel like I should be able to edit the ajax function to make it populate the existing value when editing, but maybe that is wrong approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Or if there is simply a better approach, that's great too.   I keep finding plenty of examples of cascading dropdowns that work when creating new entries to the db, but none that seem to work well on editing.

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
public JsonResult GetSubstations()
    {
        return Json(db.SubstationView.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetFeedersBySubNumber(string Substation)
    {
        string Id = Substation;

        var feed = from a in db.FeederView where a.Substation == Id select a;

        return Json(feed);
    }
```

On my Edit view, I have the following dropdown list:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Substation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Substation", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Substation", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Substation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Feeder, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Feeder", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Feeder", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Feeder, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Edit view has the following script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Orders/GetSubstations",
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {                        
                    $('#Substation').append('<option value="' + value.Substation + '">' + value.Substation + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });

        $('#Substation').change(function () {

            $('#Feeder').empty();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Orders/GetFeedersBySubNumber",
                datatype: "Json",
                data: { Substation: $('#Substation').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('#Feeder').append('<option value="' + value.Feeder + '">' + value.Feeder + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, your approach is wrong. You need to pass `SelectLists` to the view in the GET method. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym), in particular the code in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm looking over your example and trying to piece together how it works.   If I'm understanding it right, you are building lists of City/Locality/Sub Locality options in the model vs. pulling those values from a db.  I don't want to maintain a list of dropdown options in a model class when they are already in a db table.

Comment: What? Have you studied the code yet? (and how in the world do you think a DotNetFiddle can connect your database).

Comment: Stephen, first please remember I said I was new to this.  I have looked over the code and am replicating your solution in my local project.  I'm not expecting the DotNetFiddle to connect to my db.   My question was simply with how you are defining the drop down options in your public class Repository.  I need to pull the options from a db.   I'm referring to lines 32-72 in your model code.   If your solution can't pull the options from a db, it doesn't do me any good.

Comment: In your case, your view model will have properties for `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubStationList` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FeederList` and then you populate them in the controller using `model.SubStationList = db.SubstationView.Select(x => new SelectListItem(){ Value = x.??, Text = x.?? });` before you return the model to the view (and ditto for `FeederList`). And delete you first script since that dropdownlist will already be populated correctly.